# How to add Ajax progress bar to React.js application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have a submitForm(); function to send an Ajax request and return data.
How can I show a progress bar in my program.

I am using jQuery to send Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Without mentioning third party libraries (there are plenty out there that have API's for you to call to do it for you)

The most naive way is to `dispatch` something like a `isLoading` Action, the same time you fire off your API call. Then have the components you want subscribe to that part of the store, and display a whatever you please. So you can have `render()` code that looks like

```
if(this.props.isLoading){
    return <span> Loading... </span> //or whatever progress bar you want
}
else{
    //your code
}
```

And then when your API responds, you just set `isLoading` back to false, and then your components can use the responses.